# how do you use twitter bootstrap 3 with a node project

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, npm

At the moment I have a node project configured for client deployment. I am using watchify to accomplish this.  The markup is based on twitters bootstrap.  So I load twitters bootstrap in the index.html file using a cdn address.  The issue with this is I have to load jquery beforehand as well.  So I have 2 versions of jquery downloading.  One from the index.html file and the other used in the main page js.

A work around would be to able a download npm version of bootstrap but I can not find one that looks sane.  Another workaround would for me to download bootstrap file and just in include with my other js files.  This feels a bit unclean though.

Suggestions...

Comment: sounds like you would want to be using bower to manage your _application_ dependancies.  I've only typically used NPM for managing _build_ dependancies, like for all the grunt tasks / plugins you would be using to build your application (karma, clean, jshint, less, etc).

Comment: Try watchify or browersify when you get some time.  Excellent libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap guys are now supporting a node version.

https://www.npmjs.org/package/bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

It will be easy to you install already exist preconfigured project like **yeoman** (https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp). Or something like this https://github.com/wolfeidau/grunt-express-bootstrap. They already include bootstrap.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions and if I was starting the project from scratch I might consider these.

Comment: you can istall it on other folder and see bootstrap settings.

Comment: i did do that and I was unable to understand how components.json was working and where it was sourcing from.  It was also referencing bootstrap 2.